Spring boot : Unit Test for Updating Author Data in Service Layer Returning Null
I am trying to write a unit test for updating an author's data in the service layer. However, the test seems to be returning null during execution, and I am unsure why.
Here's the relevant code:
@Test
@DisplayName("Test 3: Author record Update successfully")
@Order(3)
void testUpdateAuthor_Success() {
    AuthorDTO authorDTO = new AuthorDTO();
    authorDTO.setName("Updated Author Name");

    Author existingAuthor = new Author();
    existingAuthor.setId(1L);
    existingAuthor.setName("Original Author Name");

    // Arrange
    Long authorId = 1L;
    lenient().when(authorRepository.findById(authorId)).thenReturn(Optional.of(existingAuthor));

    // Act
    ResponseEntity<ApiResponse<String>> response = authorService.updateAuthor(existingAuthor.getId(), authorDTO);

    // Assert
    // verify(authorRepository).save(existingAuthor);
    assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, response.getStatusCode());
    assertEquals("Author record updated successfully.", Objects.requireNonNull(response.getBody()).getMessage());
    assertEquals("Updated Author Name", existingAuthor.getName());
}

The issue is that the response object is returning null, causing the test to fail. I have mocked the findById method of the repository, but something seems off.
This my Service
public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse<String>> updateAuthor(Long id, @Valid AuthorDTO authorDTO) {
    logger.info("Update a author ID : {} Author Dto : {}", id, authorDTO);
    try {
        logger.info("Check existingAuthor for ID :{}", id);
        Author existingAuthor = authorRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
        if (existingAuthor != null) {
            logger.info("Updating author ID: {} author : {}", id, authorDTO);
            existingAuthor.setName(authorDTO.getName());
            authorRepository.save(existingAuthor);
            logger.info("Updated author ID: {} author : {}", id, authorDTO);
            return ResponseUtil.buildResponse(null, "Author record updated successfully.", HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            logger.info("Author data not found or empty");
            return ResponseUtil.buildResponse(null, "Author data not found.", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    } catch (OptimisticLockingFailureException e) {
        return ResponseUtil.buildResponse(null, "Conflict: Author record was modified or deleted by another process: Author Id :" + id + "=>" + e, HttpStatus.CONFLICT);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error occurred while updating author ID: {}", id, e);
        return ResponseUtil.buildResponse(null, "Error occurred while updating author with id: '" + id, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}

Has anyone experienced this issue before?
Any insights on what might be wrong with my test setup?

Don't add log output, code etc. as comments those are unreadable. Edit your question instead. When adding logs please format them using code tags as well.

@M.Deinum thanks i removed

I have fixed the issue by commenting out the line MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
